# Redirecting with K-MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout-mvc

Have a problem. For add new vacancy in my project I using K-MVC

```
public ActionResult AddVacancy()
{
    var viewModel=new VacancyViewModel();
    viewModel.AllTechnologies = (from t in _serviceClient.GetTechnologies() select t.Name).ToList();
    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddVacancy(VacancyViewModel viewModel)
{
     _serviceClient.AddVacancy(viewModel);
     return Json(viewModel);
}
```

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
@using PerpetuumSoft.Knockout
@model Core.ViewDataModel.VacancyViewModel
@{
    var ko = Html.CreateKnockoutContext();
    ViewBag.Title = "New vacancy";
}
...............................
@using (ko.Html.Form("AddVacancy", "Vacancy", ko.Model))
{
...............................................        
<p>
            <input class="submitButton" type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@ko.Apply(Model)
```

All works fine! Thanks K-MVC! 
But, if I want to redirect to another action after successful submition :

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddVacancy(VacancyViewModel viewModel)
        {
             _serviceClient.AddVacancy(viewModel);
             return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
        }
```

I'll receive error, because previous form don't receive Ajax.success. How can I manage this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't find a solution but make interface more informative to user without redirection

```
    @using (ko.If(m => m.SavedSuccessfully))
{
    @ko.Html.Span("NEW VACANCY SAVED TO DATABASE.")
}

@using (ko.If(m => m.SavedSuccessfully == false))
{
     using (ko.Html.Form("AddVacancy", "Vacancy", ko.Model))
     {
         <p>@Html.Label("Name: ")            @ko.Html.TextBox(m => m.Name).ValueUpdate(KnockoutValueUpdateKind.AfterKeyDown) </p>
         <p>@Html.Label("Active : ")         @ko.Html.CheckBox(m => m.IsOpen).ValueUpdate(KnockoutValueUpdateKind.Change) </p>
         <p>@Html.Label("English: ")         @ko.Html.DropDownList(m => m.AllLanguageLevels).Value(m => m.EnglishLevel) </p>
         <p>@Html.Label("German: ")          @ko.Html.DropDownList(m => m.AllLanguageLevels).Value(m => m.GermanLevel) </p>
         <p>@Html.Label("Technologies: ")    @ko.Html.ListBox(m => m.AllTechnologies).SelectedOptions(m => m.NeededTechnology) </p>
         <p>
             <input class="submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit" />
         </p>
     }
}
```

and controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddVacancy(VacancyViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _serviceClient.AddVacancy(viewModel);
            viewModel.SavedSuccessfully = true;
        }
        return Json(viewModel);
    }
```

And now if vacancy saved successfully - form hides and information "NEW VACANCY SAVED TO DATABASE." appears.

Comment: So there is no option to redirect to action? You can only post back a json version of the viewmodel? Because I have a similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30890625/kmvc-redirect-from-mvc-actionresult-with-json